# Moment Generating Function of Random Sum

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

You shoot a basketball $N$ times, where $N∼Geometric(q)$.  Every time you shoot you have the same probability $p$ of scoring one point (independently of other shots).  Let $X$ be the total number of points you scored.

a) Find $E(X)$.

b) Find $Var(X)$

c) Find the Moment Generating Function of $X$

I used the law of total expectation and total variance to find that $E(X) = \frac pq$ and $Var(X)=\frac {pq(1-p)+p^2(1-q)}{q^2}$, however I'm having a hard time finding the MGF of X. I tried $$E(e^{tx})=\sum_{i=0}^n E(e^{tx}|N=n)P(N=n)=\sum_{i=0}^n [(pe^t+1-p)^n]*[(1-q)^{n-1}q]$$ but this does not give me the desired result. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I would use $E(e^{tX})=E(E(e^{tX}|N))$ and then apply the MGFs of the binomial and geometric distributions

Comment: Not sure what you mean - $E(E(e^{tx}) = E((pe^t+1-p)^n)$, how do you apply geometric MGF to this?

Comment: So $(pe^t+1-p)^N=e^{Nlog(pe^t+1-p)}$ which is of the form $e^{tN}$ and so you can apply the MGF of Geo

Comment: Your sum should run from $n=...$ to $\infty$. And mgf  is $E(e^{tX})$, not $E(e^{tx})$.